# SFTP works fine from terminal, but unable to browse to sftp URL

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ssh, sftp

I'm setting up a SFTP server by following the guideline [here](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-sftp-only-user-accounts-on-centos-7) and it seems working fine, I can login to my SFTP user root directory by using sftp command:

```
    kongycmac:~ kongyc$ sftp kong@192.168.3.120
    kong@192.168.3.120's password: 
    Connected to 192.168.3.120.
    sftp>
```

and I'm able to download all the files in the SFTP folder.

Unfortunately, when I tried to open my SFTP site in my browser, it seems like not working.

In my browser address bar I key in:

```
    sftp://192.168.3.120
```

and Chrome will redirect me to Google and search for the URL. 
I'm trying to setup a SFTP URL and whenever someone browse to the SFTP link, user can login with the password and download the files.

Is there any steps that I've missed out from the configuration?

Comment: I would not expect Chrome to support the SSH protocol at all. However, you can use fuse to mount SFTP shares as network drives. If you're using Gnome, the Nautilus file manager has a menu option: *File -> Connect to Server*. It works with many network transfer protocols, including SFTP.

Comment: have you tried googling "chrome sftp plugin" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome does not support SFTP protocol.

Neither any other major web browser do.

What some browsers (like Firefox) can do, is to open the address in an external SFTP client, if the client registered to handle that protocol. For example [WinSCP SFTP client does register to handle the SFTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url) *(I'm the author of WinSCP)*.